# How to Stay in Germany

Tags: germany, eu-citizens, asylum

I am Ghanaian; I have a South Africa resident permit and am married to a South African with two children.

My wife and I came to Europe for holidays with a visitors visa and we visited my sister who is a German permanent resident. During our stay in Germany, my company in South Africa was attacked and they sent me a message not to come back if I don't want to lose my life and the one of my family.
So my wife returned alone and I extended my stay.

Now I don't have anywhere to go except to my sister so she is ready to use her resources to let me stay here in Germany in order for me not to go to South Africa to loss my life so what can we do now.

Comment: When does your visa expire? Are you asking if you can claim asylum https://handbookgermany.de/en/rights-laws/asylum/registration-for-asylumseekers.html?

Answer (score 4):

You should get a lawyer guiding you through this. You can pay one, I'm sure there are organisations to help you if you cannot afford one (probably the default if you arrive as a refugee).

You will need to explain your matter more clearly. Right now as a layman, I cannot see a reason for asylum. Surely, robbery, assault or murder is neither legal nor covered up by South African police. So it seems at first glance that protecting you at your home would be a local police matter, not a reason to flee to another continent for asylum. Asylum is meant for people that are in danger from a system they cannot escape other than fleeing said system completely.

Even if you can make the point that it is too dangerous for you in South Africa because of a greater systemic issue, the first question will be "I'm really sorry. So why didn't you go back to Ghana?"

What I want to say is this: it is important to play your cards right. You have rights here but you might not know them. You may unwittingly say something that can be seen in a certain light under a law you don't know. So go get a lawyer to help you with this.